# Error when passing input variable through to URL string

Tags: php

I feel like I'm missing something extremely simple here...but I'm getting an undefined index

```
<form action="purchase-checkout.php?MFLHistoryID=<?php echo $_GET["os0"] ?>" method="POST">
        <p>
                <input name="os0" id="os0" maxlength="5" type="text">
        </p>    
        <p>
                <button type="submit" id="checkout-button">Purchase now</button>
        </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Which script is calling this code snippet? If you are trying to access the content of a $_GET['index'] variable make sure it exists. I guess the undefined index here is about $_GET["os0"]? You could check for its existence before calling its value.

Comment: Also, if os0 is coming from this same script: your form will be delivering the form input in a POST request. You won't be getting os0 by using the $_GET variable, but rather from $_POST.

Comment: Finally, it looks like you may have recursion here.  Does the **input** define the **os0**, which you then use to create the said **input** in the past ?